# Turning string currency numbers inside a dataframe into float using Python or Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
df:
                    CNPJ       last_revenues
0     01.637.895/0001-32       R$ 12.696.658
1     02.916.265/0001-60   R$ 162.914.526,04
2     02.932.074/0001-91        R$ 1.928.312
3     03.853.896/0001-40    R$ 19.333.453,92
```

The values in the column "last_revenues" are strings of currency values in latin format. I need to turn them into floats, it would have to look like this:

```
df:
                    CNPJ       last_revenues
0     01.637.895/0001-32       12696658.0000
1     02.916.265/0001-60      162914526.0400
2     02.932.074/0001-91        1928312.0000
3     03.853.896/0001-40       19333453.9200
```

### Edit

Actually I noticed that there are a few nan's in the middle of it. So my df looks like this:

```
df:
                    CNPJ       last_revenues
0     01.637.895/0001-32       R$ 12.696.658
1     02.916.265/0001-60   R$ 162.914.526,04
2     02.932.074/0001-91                 nan
3     03.853.896/0001-40    R$ 19.333.453,92
```

And I want to make it look like this:

```
df:
                    CNPJ       last_revenues
0     01.637.895/0001-32       12696658.0000
1     02.916.265/0001-60      162914526.0400
2     02.932.074/0001-91                 nan
3     03.853.896/0001-40       19333453.9200
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it, is to `apply` a conversion function to each element in `last_revenues`. This can be done in many ways, but as a `lambda` one liner it *can* be written as:

```
df['last_revenues'] = df['last_revenues'].dropna().apply(lambda rstr: float(rstr.replace('.','').replace(',','.')[3:]))
```

Here I first I drop all nan values, thereafter I replace all dots with nothing, then the comma with a dot. Finally I remove the initial currency characters and convert the resulting string to a float.

Comment: Actually this is getting the following error: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: Not when I try it at my computer. Maybe your underlaying data is already floats, so that it is just a matter of representation and not actually conversion?

Comment: Is replace from a specific library?

Comment: `.replace()` is a string method. Thus it assumes rstr, i.e. your elements, to be strings. It is not from any special library.

Comment: I think I found the problem. I didn't notice there are a few NaNs in the middle of df.last_revenues. Do you know how could I skip that?

Comment: @abutremutante `df['last_revenues'] = df['last_revenues'].apply(lambda rstr: float(rstr.replace('.','').replace(',','.')[3:]) if rstr != 'nan')` should work

Comment: Thanks @ZuluDeltaNiner but I'm getting this error "df['last_revenues'] = df['last_revenues'] .apply(lambda rstr: float(rstr.replace('.','').replace(',','.')[3:]) if rstr != 'nan')
                                                                                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax". Any idea what it could be? Might be something simple, but I tried a few things and didn't figure out.

Comment: @ZuluDeltaNiner it points to the last parenthesis, just after 'nan'

Comment: Try adding `else None` before the last parenthesis @abutremutante. Sorry I can't be fully sure as I am away from a machine with python on it.

Comment: Tried that before too and it didn't work :/ Also tried to create a new question so @JohanL could keep the merits for making this one right (afterall he was right) but moderator closed as a duplicate. I'm afraid I will have to edit this one and keep it unanswered. Sorry guys.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147410/discussion-between-zuludeltaniner-and-abutremutante).

Comment: I have added an update to handle also the `nan` values. However, the one liner is becoming quite horrible. Maybe it would be good to split it into multiple lines. :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things required:

1. Detect nan
2. Trim the leading currency (separated by space) (`rstr.split(' ')[1]`)
3. Convert the currency string to int

   ```
   df['last_revenues'] = df['last_revenues'].apply(lambda rstr: '{:5.4f}'.format(float(rstr.split(' ')[1].replace('.','').replace(',', '.'))) if rstr != 'nan' else 'nan')
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
df.last_revenues.replace('R\$ ','',inplace=True,regex=True)
df.last_revenues.replace('\.','',inplace=True,regex=True)
df.last_revenues.replace(',','.',inplace=True,regex=True)
```